# Does there exist a data structure in cpp that easily provides a way to build a new one, based on an instance that already exists?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, data-structures

The type of operation I'm looking for would go as follows, but of course this code doesn't work.

```
int a[3] = {0,1,2};
int b[3] = (a[2] = 0);
```

This way the array b has elements `{0,1,0}` and a has `{0,1,2}`

Comment: Most C++ data structures have copy constructors where you can make `b` a copy of `a` and then change only the elements you need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does there exist a data structure in cpp that easily provides a way to build a new one, based on an instance that already exists?

Pretty much all standard containers are copyable. You can implement your example using `std::array`:

```
std::array a{0,1,2};
std::array b = a;
b[2] = 0;
```

Comment: `std::array<int>`

Comment: @john: no longer needed with [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) since C++17.

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting, I'm still catching up with C++11.